# Limiting type of SELECT queries in SQL expression

Tags: sql, select

I would like to know if there is any way to prevent SQL database from executing queries which do not contain any aggregate functions. The reason is preventing user from fetching the data of particular record (e.g. personal information), but giving him the option to query the population (e.g. average age). I would like not to write any wrapper/processor/parser if there is any out-of-box solution.

Comment: Don't grant access to the table/column. Create a view, grant select on it.

Comment: Not a good idea. What if I group by primary key and use analytic functions like `MAX`, `MIN` to access value from the only row in each group? That would satisfy your requirement but I'd still get that personal info in my resultset. If you do not want someone to access sensitive information, do not grant access to it at all. Views should do fine as @jarlh suggested.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Any. I was asking for a name of mechanism or a general concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real (or at least easy) way to do this.

Recommendation would be to restrict access to the basetables but create one or more views over the top which provide the aggregate data, and then allow access to this.

Alternatively, create 1-to-1 mapped views that simply select only non-personal data from the basetable. This way you can let someone use these views to run aggregate functions without worry of exposing personal or sensitive information.

The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) for views states:

> Views can represent a subset of the data contained in a table. Consequently, a view can limit the degree of exposure of the underlying tables to the outer world: a given user may have permission to query the view, while denied access to the rest of the base table.

and

> Views can act as aggregated tables, where the database engine aggregates data (sum, average, etc.) and presents the calculated results as part of the data.